# Jenkins (JVM) crashes after few minutes after start

Tags: openvz, hudson, java, jenkins

- Host OS: **OpenVZ host**
- Guest OS: **Debian 6.0 minimal**
- Java: **java6 sun**
- Servlet container: **Winstone**
- Jenkins for debian: http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/
- Jenkins version: **1.449**
- uname -a: **Linux hostname 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5.028stab089.1 #1 SMP Thu Apr 14 14:06:01 MSD 2011 i686 GNU/Linux**
- **JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx128m -Xms64m -Xrs -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/java-jenkins-dumps -XX:PermSize=128m"**
- free -m:

> ```
>               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
> Mem:          2048        532       1515          0          0          0
> -/+ buffers/cache:        532       1515
> Swap:            0          0          0
> ```

After crash:

- jenkins latests line output: **INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running**
- syslog output: **Jan 31 17:50:02 cherry jenkins: jenkins: fatal: client (pid 16189) killed by signal 15, exiting**
- user_beancounters has 0 failcnt

**The question: what else to debug? Is it worth trying to change servlet container (to tomcat)?**

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed a similar issue on one our servers.  For some reason the VM we have running Jenkins was using a small memory configuration and the swap partition wasn't currently used.  My guess is that at some point Java attempts to allocate a large amount of memory and is killed by the OOM task.

After making sure that the swap partition was activated via a fstab entry the problem went away.

TLDR: you need more virtual or physical memory.

Comment: Did you notice anything in logs? This results in no output for me: egrep -r -i "killed process" /var/log/

Comment: yeah there were messages in the the log that jenkins had been killed.  However - that is likely linux specific.

Comment: I have no such log entry present, that's why I'm doubting.

Comment: You're probably forking a load of processes so is a good candidate for Linux OOM killer to kick in. You won't see much logging from the JDK as it's being force killed. /var/log/messages should mention OOM.

Comment: Also, you really should allocate some swap to your box. It may be enough for Linux to page off enough to run everything you need.